# Cannot make a hair with bezier curve and circle

Tags: modeling, hair

[image]I am a newbie.
I try to make hair with bezier circle and path.
After selecting path, go under geometry to pick object target, it doesn't recognize circle.
Under object list, there is only one NurvsPath.
If I pick circle first, it recognize path, so it make disk like shape.
What can be a problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have the bevel object of the bezier circle set to the nurbs path, but I believe this is backwards. I believe you should have set the bevel object of the nurbs path set to bezier circle, as you intially tried to do.

Make sure that when you have the path selected, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvRK6.jpg . The nestedness of the collections doesn't have to match what I did, but focus on the way I selected the path.

See how the logo to the left of the object, "NurbsPath" and how it's highlighted? This indicates that the NurbsPath is the active object. Your active object is the Circle, so I would avoid doing any shift-selects if that's the cause.

Comment: Actually, I tried it opposite way. First nurbs path and then bezier circle but as I described, it didn't work. Circle was not recognized at all. Cannot pick it. I add the picture just just to show you that opposite way seems working.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I know that if you do it the way you have it set up, you'll always get some sort of circular strip with no tubing. I believe the correct way is opposite to yours, but I'm not sure why the bezier  circle isn't being recognized. Could you attach the blend file to this post and tell me, if there is one, which error is displaying on screen when it's not being recognized?

Comment: This is the error message from log file and as you see, there are two curve but under object, only path exist. Is it clear for my question? By the way, thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: see edit to answer

Comment: I go back and try again. Thanks